# How can I update an object array in sequence with an array for and argument with .map() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

I'm a beginner-level student and for practice in understanding `.map()`, I'm trying to write a callback function that returns an updated list of full names that would return Jim's last name as Smith etc. `employees[0].familyName = lastNames[0]`, `employees[1].familyName = lastNames[1]` and so on....

```
const lastNames = ["Smith", "Anderson"];

const employees = [
  {
    name: "Jim",
    familyName:"",
  },
  {
    name: "Jill",
    familyName: "",
    
  }
];
```

This is what I've tried expecting it to return a new object array called `fullNames` with the following key/value pairs but am lost in the wrong direction possibly with matching the index numbers:

```
function lastNameUpdater(arr, objArr) {
  let matchNumber = arr.findIndex() === objArr.findIndex();
  const fullNames = objArr.map((element) => {
    return matchNumber;
    if (matchNumber) {
      return objArr.key = arr;
    }
    return fullNames;
  })
}

lastNameUpdater(lastNames, employees);
```

Comment: [`map` has a second parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#parameters) which is the index of the current iterated element. You can use that index within the callback to grab the corresponding element from `lastNames`, and return a new object.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the second `index` parameter that's passed to the callback, then you can use [spread notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to overwrite the `familyName` attribute. Because the indices match up, this will pair each family name with the correct employee:

```js
function update(employees, lastNames) {
  return employees.map(function(employee, index) {
    return {...employee, familyName: lastNames[index]}
  });
}

const lastNames = ["Smith", "Anderson"];
const employees = [
  {
    name: "Jim",
    familyName:"",
  },
  {
    name: "Jill",
    familyName: "",
    
  }
];

console.log(update(employees, lastNames))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the index argument given to the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) callback to access the corresponding last name from the other array.

```js
const lastNames = ["Smith", "Anderson"];
const employees = [
  {
    name: "Jim",
    familyName:"",
  },
  {
    name: "Jill",
    familyName: "",
  }
];
const res = employees.map((o, i) => ({...o, familyName: lastNames[i]}));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Since OP is a beginner you'll probably have to explain what the spread operator is and why it's used.

Comment: Thank you so much. Is the spread operator's use is because of what was mentioned in one of the solutions above, that the last name is "overwritten" rather than being "filled in",  or does it have to do with variables passed by reference? None of the above? Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: @A-S-Hemphill Spread syntax here copies all the properties of the original object into a new object. We can add more properties after the spread to introduce entirely new keys or to overwrite previous values.

Answer (score 1):

You are misusing findIndex; actually, you don't even need it. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

What you really need is to use the [map's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) second argument, which is the `index` of the current element in the array, and pick the element under the same index in the `lastNames` array.

```
const lastNames = ['Smith', 'Anderson'];

const employees = [
  {
    name: 'Jim',
    familyName: '',
  },
  {
    name: 'Jill',
    familyName: '',
  },
];

function lastNameUpdater(arr, objArr) {
  const fullNames = objArr.map((element, index) => ({
    ...element,
    familyName: arr[index],
  }));
  return fullNames;
}

// [
//     { name: 'Jim', familyName: 'Smith' },
//     { name: 'Jill', familyName: 'Anderson' }
// ]
console.log(lastNameUpdater(lastNames, employees));
```